# Windows remote from Mac mouse button issues

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, remote, remapping

I'm using Microsoft RDC to remote into my work PC from my MacBook. I recently got a Logitech MX Master 3 mouse and have been running into some issues with the button/gesture mapping within remote.

When the the mouse software is enabled (Security and Privacy > Input Monitoring > Logi Options Daemon checked) everything works fine in Mac, but the forward/back buttons stop working in Windows remote. When the software/extra functionalities are disabled (Logi Options Daemon unchecked) none of the extra features work at all (gestures, thumb button, side scroll), it's just basic mouse functionality (clicking, scrolling, forward/back button) but it all works in Windows remote too.

I've tried with the buttons specifically programmed to be forward/back, as well as remapped them to <kbd>Opt</kbd>+Left/Right for the windows shortcut, but this doesn't work either. I think the problem is that the Windows computer isn't recognizing <kbd>Opt</kbd> as <kbd>Alt</kbd> for some reason. I have no idea why it works just fine when the Logi Daemon option is turned off but immediately stops working when it's turned on.

It's an awfully specific question, but it seems like there should be some way to make it work and have full mouse functionality plus forward/back buttons that work in remote. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Opt key should be mapped to AltR on US-PC keyboard and AltGr on non-US PC keyboard.

Comment: I can't suggest a fix, all I can do is confirm it doesn't work. From the keyboard, either Opt key + arrow works, but assigning MX buttons to forward/back or Opt+arrow in Logi Options doesn't. I suspect the ball is in Logitech's court. There are many oddities in Logi stuff on Mac.

Comment: @harrymc how would I go about doing this? and do you mean within macOS or the remote windows PC?

Comment: I mean within macOS, but unfortunately I'm not on the Mac. I know this has been done, but I don't know how.

Comment: macOS doesn't differentiate between right & left Opt, only Windows does.  Mac can emulate it by just pressing Opt & Ctrl together, which is actually all Windows does internally, it doesn't use the 'true' AltGr either, that got left behind decades ago on old Sun machines, etc. There's nothing to remap. RDC sends the physical keys correctly over to Windows, but Logi Options doesn't. It's a Logi bug.